# How to run 2 wordpress blogs using docker on ec2

Tags: dotcloud, docker

I just started playing around with Docker.io. Its a great platform for sure. I have an issue i need some help with. I ran a medium instance on ec2 setup docker. Now i want to run 2 wordpress blog independent of each other using docker.io on top of the medium instance.

Please if someone can kindly guide me to resolve this issue i will extremely grateful

Many Thanks Indeed
Hareem Haque

Updated:

Basically, what i am trying to do is run two nodes for docker (node 1 & node 2). I run another node (node3: private repo for docker). What i am looking to accomplish is i run two blogs (wordpress on node1). I export the docker images to node3 (updates/exports are done very rarely)

Since i am going to run wordpress i was hoping to run wordpress within Nginx and since node1/node2 will run 80 web i can put a physical node (nginx reverse proxy) in front of the two nodes and have the blogs run in ha mode.

I am hoping that this experiment work so i that i can get rid of the xen cloud platform we have in office. Its to bulky and I have to manage alot of components.
I would rather export/backup docker image with my live data once in a blue moon and not have to worry about failover and vm management.

The problem is that i have a novice when it comes to running docker and thus i am currently running around like a head less chicken with no idea where to properly begin.

I would be extremely grateful if you can provide any guidance/assistance indeed.

Best Regards
Hareem Haque

Comment: What have you done so far? can you explain the steps you have already done, and where you are stuck so we know where you need help?

Comment: I am interested in doing something similar. I guess the blogs need to be on different TCP ports, while the proxy accepts incoming port 80 and forwards to each container as appropriate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hareem asked his question a while back, and there don't seem to be any good answers yet. I'm a noobie as well, and I too want to learn how to use a generic wordpress container that I can push to Amazon or test locally. I'm very new to docker, so this seems like a tall order!

#### Goal

For now, I'll start collecting some resources here. Maybe they will help Hareem, and others like myself. This document will turn into a complete answer, or prompt someone else to give their version of an answer (which I'm sure is not quite so complex.)

#### The Docker.io Index

First, the Docker index is a repository of already existing Docker.io components. Of these, there is a wordpress unit that seems relevant here:

- jbfink - [Wordpress 3.5.2.](https://index.docker.io/u/jbfink/wordpress/)

#### Docker on EC2

There is as yet no official Docker support for Ec2. However, the Docker community suggests an install path using a tool called Vagrant. The instructions for this live here:

- Docker Doc - [Installing on Amazon EC2](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/amazon/)

#### Work In Progress

This is not a complete answer to the question. As of right now this only presents a couple of easy to locate resources, and perhaps goes against guidelines. Please bear with this!

Things that need to be answered:

- How do we run / test the wordpress container(s) locally?
- How do we push the container(s) up to the EC2 instance?
- How do we wire the EC2 wordpress containers up to their own domains?

Hopefully I will answer these questions - contributions and forks are welcome. I think Hareem's question is worth answering!