# Using AWS Simple Workflow to start a docker container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-swf

I am totally newbie using AWS Simple Workflow, but before I start learning I would like to know if it is possible to run a docker container inside a EC2 instance.

I know that my EC2 instance has a ECS Agent, so I imagine that i cant send a START TASK to this ecs daemon.

Does anyone has experience doing this?

Answer (score 1):

AWS documentation on docker:  [Docker Basics ECS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)  
As per the documentation, docker can be started using 'sudo service docker start'

This is an old post, but I think this may be still relevant for your question.

 [Docker On EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902698/how-to-run-2-wordpress-blogs-using-docker-on-ec2)

Comment: The ECS service is designed to do exactly what the questions is asking about. Of course you can also manually run a docker container on an EC2 instance. ECS is just designed to help manage the deployment and scaling.